# Feature request - auto suggest addition of schematic to OP when not included

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, schematic

I hope this won't be received badly.

I was wondering if a feature for the questions pertaining to circuit problems and debugging.

What I noticed is a lot of questions asking for help with a circuit sometimes don't have a schematic accompanying the  question and this usually ends with people in comments asking for the person to post a circuit. This would probably end in the question being closed or ignored by the community.
I am sure when they ask their first question they might or might not read the page on asking questions.

What I was thinking of suggesting is that when the user types something matching a phrase containing common words like:

> schematic, circuit, problem, not working, help

When these are detected, then at the point of the person submitting the question, it could be checked to see if there is a schematic, if not it should have a pop up to suggest the addition of a schematic, else if there is one it can be submitted.

I would like to know the opinion on this and if I am asking too much?

Comment: It won't be hard to implement, but with the experience on other sites with keyword based extra popups is probably that it won't help at all

Comment: @PlasmaHH - I'm sure it wouldn't be hard to implement, that's why I asked;). My thought though is that it should restrict the asker from posting hence making them put something on.

Comment: Due to the possibility of false positives of that algorithm there always needs to be the option to proceed without adding a schematics. The kind of people you are talking about is not only not reading any faq, help, guidelines, popping up related questions and possibly already answered questions, they will also ignore that dialogue and see it as yet another nuisance click to get to their answer that is very important personally for them right now.

Comment: @PlasmaHH - I get where there are false positives, non-circuit images and such too would also cause issues. I guess forcing someone to add an image would push away useful questions too, it should be optional then. I agree that people who never read FAQ and such won't care about something to help there question answerable, maybe it could still be put in to help those who actually want a meaningful answer and not a load of flak.

Comment: Given the amount of different info popups on different stacks it seems that something like "if text contains circuit add popup "did you maybe want to attach a circuit?"" is a simple configuration thing

Comment: Less effort to code that in then. Maybe make a big red one to catch there attention :) Aside it would work nice if the user has 'datasheet' or 'circuit' with an embedded link that it possible doesn't have a pop up. But these are theoretical I guess.

Comment: @CamilStaps if its a duplicate then it is obviously something that needs to be done because there are a lot of people not following the hints. And yours deals with it happening on the addition of tags, whereas mine deals with the fact it should come up from something in the question, not exactly a duplicate.